# Dreamweaver how to get properties bar back

Tags: properties, dreamweaver

Oh my word. I struggle with the actual codeing of my website, and now something sooooo stupid has to happen....
In dreamweaver.. i think i pressed the wrong button or something, and now i cant fix it..
You know on the right hand side (usually) there is a window where you can set the properties of lets say a textbox. Like its name, its contents, its id etc. 
That box has dissapeared... Now theres only some random boxes of properties i have NOOOO idea what for... 
Can any one tell me how i can get that back please? The default ones back? (like a reset settings button somewhere?
Thank you!
Ruan.

Comment: Guess no one knows. Oh well, cant know everything i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Window menu and select Properties to get it back.  Alternately, Control-F3.